# Getting Infographics within shapefile boundary using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, infographics

I just got ArcGIS Pro and have been googling around trying to figure this out.

How do i get the [Infographics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/infographics.htm) that are within a shapefile?

I would like to know the population that lives within the shapefile

Comment: I'm adding a comment as I don't currently have ArcGIS Pro installed to verify this, but I believe you must have a spatial reference set for your shapefile.  If this is set then the infographics should just pop-up when you use the tool.  It doesn't load data from the shapefile itself, it pulls it from a Esri webservice (if I'm thinking of the same thing!)

Comment: From your ESRI link : "Note:
You must be signed in with an ArcGIS Organizational account, with available credits, to use the service."

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend referencing ArcGIS Pro documentation on [Infographics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/infographics.htm). I haven't seen this feature avaialable for ArcGIS Pro at this point. It seems that the current availability for this option is via the templates.

> Infographics present key indicators and summarized information for locations through templates of interactive charts, tables, maps, and images.